# Workbench Not Showing new API version 59.0

Tags: workbench

I'm required to use newly created standard objects which are available in API 59.0 version. Workbench doesn't show the new API version when using the standard SOQL query. Please help me out if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

Workbench is not an official part of Salesforce, and is in "Maintenance Only" mode.

It will eventually be updated by the maintainers to offer the v59.0 API, but there's not really any timeline for when that'll happen. It took about 2 months after release for support of v58.0 to be added.

When you use free tools, you're completely at the mercy of whoever is maintaining it.

If this is something that you need *now*, then your best options are:

- Find and pay for a tool that is actively being developed
- Use the official tools/APIs (REST API, Metadata API, Tooling API, Developer Console, Web UI, VSCode extensions, etc...)

Comment: And just to make things clear, I am not a maintainer of the Workbench. I've probably looked into the code more than most (which is to say I've spent about a total of 4 hours looking through the code), but that's about it.